# List subfunctions defined in function file within calling environment

Tags: matlab

I have a function defined like the following in a `.m` file:

```
function main_fn()
...
end

function sub_fn1()
...
end

function sub_fn2()
....
end
...

function sub_fnN()
...
end
```

i.e. standard structure with main function first followed by subfunctions accessible by the main function when it is called.

I know that you can use `whos` within the function calling environment to return the variables stored in the function call stack. I would like to retrieve the sub-functions defined within the function file, and return them as a cell array of function handles.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:** the answer by @nirvana-msu has made my original request possible. However, now I find that it is more convenient to store these functions in a struct, so that I can refer to them by name:

For example:

```
fcn = 
    struct('sub_fn1', @sub_fn1, ...
           'sub_fn2', @sub_fn2, ...
           ...
           )
```

**EDIT 2:**
It is simply to convert the cell array obtained in the answer to a struct, simply use `func2str`:

```
fcns = cell2struct(fncs, cellfun(@func2str, fncs, 'uni', 0));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`localfunctions`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/localfunctions.html) - introduced in R2013b:

```
function main_fn()
    fcns = localfunctions();
end

function sub_fn1()
end

function sub_fn2()
end

function sub_fnN()
end
```

It returns a cell array of function handles to all local functions in your file:

```
fcns = 
    @sub_fn1
    @sub_fn2
    @sub_fnN
```